# AGM Angular Google Maps imagery not loading

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

It seems that reaching out to googleapis.com with AGM fails unless I have the 
googleapis.com script tag in the head of my index.html

***AGM initialization in my module***

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
apiKey: 'MyKey',
libraries: ['imagery', 'places']
}),
```

***Script tag in head***

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=MyKey=imagery,places">
</script>
```

If I don't include the script tag I get the error...

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/10a/imagery.js 
net::ERR_ABORTED 404
Ae @ js? 
v=3&callback=agmLazyMapsAPILoader&key=MyKey&libraries=imagery,places:81
(anonymous) 
zone.js:682 Unhandled Promise rejection: Could not load "imagery". ; Zone: 
<root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Could not load "imagery".
```

I need to be able to use AGM independently of doing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

***UPDATE***

I'm not loading "libraries" correctly in my AgmCoreModule...but I can't find how to do it correctly

***UPDATE***

All you have to do to get imagery tiles to load is set the

```
[mapTypeId]="satellite"
```

Now my problem is that the imagery tiles do not load unless I zoom in or out on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved through the comments above...more information here [AGM Google maps imagery tiles not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930412/agm-google-maps-imagery-tiles-not-loading)