# AGM Google maps imagery tiles not loading

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

Imagery tiles do not load when the page loads...I have to take some action on the map i.e.(zoom,pan) then the tiles load

***AGM initialization in my module***

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
apiKey: 'MyKey'
}),
```

***My agm-map tag***

```
   <agm-map  
   [latitude]="lat"
   [longitude]="lng"
   [zoom]="zoom"
   [mapTypeId]="mapType" 
   [mapTypeControl]="mapControls" 
   [zoomControl]="mapControls" 
   [streetViewControl]="mapControls">
   </agm-map>
```

How can I force tiles to load?

Comment: Can you share me code snippet to load tiles on map. Badly looking for solution

Comment: Have you looked here https://angular-maps.com/

Comment: Yes.. agm-overlay worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that when you are using AGM Angular google Maps that you initialize the map with proper lat/lng values...if you do not the map just does nothing, it's especially confusing if you have all the map controls set to "false" like I did.

Mystery solved

Comment: I am also looking to load images on map. Is there is any AGm library available for the same?